# SVN Authentication and authorization

Tags: svn, maven-scm

I have created a multi module maven project. Now I have shared the project with a internal SVN repository.

Now I want to give authorization to user based on the module user is owner of. So if a user does not have right to a project; he/she will not be able to checkout the project form svn repository. But he/she will get a source release(sources.jar file) form maven repository for that project; if wanted.

What should i do go get this done?

My svn reposiroty is created by TortoiseSVN 1.6.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look on the documentation at [Authentication | TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/authentication)